# Why JavaScript work on pc but dont work on phone?

Tags: javascript, html

I made JS code for email and checkbox validation, on PC the validaton works, but it doesnt work on phone. the error messages dont change and the checkbox message dont dissapear when the checkbox is checked

I tested it with multiple phones and chrome -> f12 -> phone icon... 
It does not show any errors in console too...

**Question:** Why and how to fix that?

**My Code:**

```js
   

function validationemail()
{
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var email_error = document.getElementById("email_error");
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    var valid_email = /(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/;

    if (checkBox.checked == false) {
        /* Checkbox is unchecked */
        text.innerHTML = "You must accept the terms and conditions";
        text.style.display = "unset";
        text.style.color = "#ff0000";

    } else {
        /* checkbox is checked */
        text.innerHTML = "";
        text.style.display = "unset";
        text.style.color = "#ff0000";
    }

    if (email.length === 0) {
        /* email is empty */
    } else if (!email.match(valid_email)) {
        /* email is invalid */
        form.classList.remove("valid");
        form.classList.add("invalid");
        email_error.innerHTML = "Please provide a valid e-mail address";
        email_error.style.display = "unset";
        email_error.style.color = "#ff0000";

    } else if (email.endsWith('.co')) {
        /* email ends with .co */
        form.classList.remove("valid");
        form.classList.add("invalid");
        email_error.innerHTML = "We are not accepting subscriptions from Colombia";
        email_error.style.display = "unset";
        email_error.style.color = "#ff0000";

    } else {
        /* email is valid */
        form.classList.remove("valid");
        form.classList.add("invalid");
        email_error.innerHTML = "";
        email_error.style.display = "unset";
        email_error.style.color = "#ff0000";
    }

}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="#">

    <div class="email_form">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Type your email address here…" oninput="validationemail()">
        <span id="email_error" style="color: red; display: unset"> Email address is required </span>

    </div>

    <p class="terms-text"> <input onchange="validationemail()" type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="myCheck"> I agree to <a href="#" class="terms-text-button">terms of service</a> </p>
    <span id="text" style="color: red; display: unset" > You must accept the terms and conditions </span>
</form>
```

Comment: What doesn't work on phone? Can you be more specific and show the errors if any?

Comment: What model phone and browser?

Comment: I have tried in chrome's mobile but it works correctly, can you tell me which modal are you using which is not responding ?

Comment: @Dhara Samsung galaxy a21s

Comment: I have tried galaxy s3, galaxy note 2, galaxy note 3. it still works. it didn't show a21s. please tell me how can I configure that so I can test it and provide the solution quickly

Comment: @Dhara if you mean how you can check it on samsung galaxy a21s, then mybe use some emulator?

Comment: Alright, meanwhile can you check on galaxy s3, galaxy note 2 and confirm if it works or not properly?

Comment: can you try doing this on your javascript file: `myjavascriptfile.js?v=0315211019` I always do it in mmddyyHHtt format. doing so will ensure that all device will use a fresh push of your javascript file.

Comment: @kapitan That does not work :(